# determine in code if android WebView web contents debugging enabled

Tags: android, cordova, webview, android-ndk

Is it possible to tell at runtime if an android (cordova) application's WebViews are remote debug enabled (eg via chrome inspector)  and if so how ?

So for instance, if the WebView started out as non-debuggable (a typical release build app) and then at some point 
`static void WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)` is called, can I either catch this as an event or read the new state ?

Any approach ( Javacript,Java or C/C++/NDK ) which doesn't involve building a modified webkit will do.